# Phase shift oscillator

Tags: amplifier, gain, oscillation

I arranged an RC phase shift oscillator with an LM324 op amp in a buffered mode using all the amplifier of the quad op amp. I set the gain to be 8.33 using Rf as 1 MΩ and Rin as 120k. 3 stage RC network are 560 Ω and 10 µf capacitors. Input voltage is 5 V but it didn’t oscillate. What might be wrong?

[image]

[image]

<sup>Original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9NBP.jpg</sup>

Comment: set the gain to unlimited, then work down until it stops.

Answer (score 1):

> *Input voltage is 5volts but it didn’t oscillate*

Your circuit has multiple problems: -

[image]

(1) - If you are grounding the non-inverting input then you will need a negative supply

(2) - Your op-amps negative supply is floating irrespective of (1).

You may have other errors but these are the most striking.

Answer (score 0):

Question: Are you speaking about simulation or hardware experiment?

In general, the dimensioning of the oscillator is OK - in particular the gain stage. However, you should work with split supply.
Moreover, for a safe start of oscillations you should increase the gain by app. 5...10%.

Furthermore, in case of simulation you must give one of the capacitors an initial condition of some millivolts (for a safe start). Alternatively, you could switch on the power supplies at t=0. Otherwise. The tran analysis cannot show the oscillation.